# How can I put WhatsApp number, Mail and location like this with icons?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, web

[my english is not that good, sorry]
This picture I snapped from https://icms.edu.pk/ I want to know how can I put these whatsapp, mail-us and location like in this on my page.
Can someone please help me out?

Firstly, I thought that these are images but they are not.

Comment: Use your browser's dev tools inspect factility to see exactly what code is producing that icon. You will see that it invokes flaticon. You will need to search for that to find out how to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use icons and for phone number use `tel:<-- phone number -->` inside the *anchor tag* and for mail use `mailto:<-- mail id -->` inside the *anchor tag*
or you can try the example mentioned below:

**index.html**

```
   <div class="header-contact">
      <div id="phone-details" class="widget-text">
        <i class="fa-brands fa-whatsapp"></i>
        <div class="info-text">
          <a href="tel:+92 333-9119145">
            <span>WhatsApp</span> +92 333-9119145
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

and here is **style.css**

```
.header-contact .widget-text {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 55px;
}
.header-contact .widget-text i {
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 2px;
  text-align: center;
  left: 0;
  line-height: 40px;
  color: #003e78;
  font-size: 35px;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
  transition: all .3s ease;
  font-weight: 700;
}
.header-contact .widget-text .info-text a {
  color: #505050;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 16px;
}
a {
  color: #D6F8D6;
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
  text-decoration: none !important;
  outline: none !important;
}
.header-contact .widget-text .info-text span {
  display: block;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #101010;
  line-height: 18px;
}
```

and one more here I can use a [fontawesome icons](https://fontawesome.com/v6/docs/web/setup/get-started)

Comment: They aren't using fontawesome at this point.

Comment: do you want that icon

Comment: Incorrect WhatsApp link. It's not `tel:` protocol, it should be `https://wa.me/923339119145`

Comment: but above I mentioned tel: for a phone number so read that paragraph

Answer (score 0):

They are using an icons library - [www.flaticon.com](https://www.flaticon.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Check this website `https://fontawesome.com/`

Once you signup (it's free), you will get a script like this:

```
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/e1861f2b78.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Add this to your `head` tag.

Then search for the font you need and get the link for the icon.

You can customize it using CSS properties, check out the [Font Awesome Howto](https://fontawesome.com/docs/web/add-icons/how-to) if you need clarification.

Comment: It's not a fontawesome icon that is being used at this point.

Comment: then it might be .PNG

Comment: They are using flaticons.